# how to upload files to Google Cloud Storage with symfony / gauferette / VichUploaderBundle

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, vichuploaderbundle, gaufrette

Good morning,

I am uploading my files **locally** through VichUploaderBundle. Every thing works perfectly.

Now I want no more store my files locally: I want to store them on **Google Cloud Storage**. I found that **KnpGaufretteBundle** could be used for storing files in the cloud.

So, is there any example or a example's link on how to configure **Gaufrette** *(the php package)* or **KnpGaufretteBundle** *(the symfony bundle)* for storing/uploading/reading files on `google-cloud-storage`?

The only thing I found is that [link](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/spec/Gaufrette/Adapter/GoogleCloudStorageSpec.php)  which is an adapter class for GoogleCloudStorage.

I found another link regarding this issue but it proposes an example for storing files on `amazon-s3`: [upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-symfony2-and-gaufrette](https://florian.ec/articles/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-symfony2-and-gaufrette/)

Thanks for you help...

Answer (score 2):

Is possible to use KnpGaufretteBundle to do that. You only need to create a factory that creates a Google Client fully authenticated and return the Google Service Storage with that Client. Something like that:

```
/**
 * @return \Google_Service_Storage
 */
public function createService($privateKeyPath, $password, $googleAccountName)
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $scopes = array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write'
    );

    $privateKey = file_get_contents($privateKeyPath);

    $credential = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $googleAccountName, $scopes, $privateKey, $password
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credential);

    return new \Google_Service_Storage($client);
}
```

You also need to configure the KnpGaufretteBundle, for this look at:
[KnpGaufretteBundle-GoogleCloudStorage](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle#googlecloudstorage)

Here there's a post in GitHub where explains the factory issue:
[post](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/issues/123)

Comment: On github, it is me mappedinn. Thank you for being helpul